# Rails CanCan: Doesn't CanCan assume I can :read if I can :update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, declarative-authorization, cancan

This works for an authorize! call

```
can [:read,:update], brand
```

but CanCan::AccessDenied is thrown when the line in the Ability class is changed to:

```
can :update, brand
```

brand is not nil.

If I can :update something, shouldn't I automatically be able to :read it?

I just want to know if this is by design, or if I am missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. There are just few default aliases defined:

```
def default_alias_actions
  {
    :read => [:index, :show],
    :create => [:new],
    :update => [:edit],
  }
end
```

So if someone has 'update' right then he has 'edit' right. This is natural for Rails applications which follow REST style.

However you can [define](http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/master/CanCan/Ability#alias_action-instance_method) your own aliases very simply.